# Pods are evicted due to Container airflow-worker exceeded its local ephemeral storage limit "10137Mi" in google composer

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-composer

I'm using **google Composer version** **1.18.0** which is having **Airflow version 2.2.3** and the worker node count is set to 4 with a Disk Size of 100 GB and machine type **n1-standard-2** and

```
Web server machine type=composer-n1-webserver-2 (2 vCPU, 1.6 GB memory)

Cloud SQL machine type=db-n1-standard-2 (2 vCPU, 7.5 GB memory)
```

number of schedulers is 1 and the rest of the other configs are almost basic.

I have just moved 4 jobs into this and I'm already seeing POD evicted due to this below error

**Container airflow-worker exceeded its local ephemeral storage limit "10137Mi".**

I have tried contacting google support team, they told to create a new environment with enough resources and this one newly created as autopilot in another older environment is not working as expected and also pods are all evicted with the same error, so we creatd this above config environment with enough resources but still seeing this error and not sure how to get rid of this.

PFA screenshots for reference
[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me here

YAML FILE

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Pod
    metadata:
    annotations:
          composer.cloud.google.com/running-task: "true"
          composer.cloud.google.com/template-version: 
           919cc331f4a25a332a1e0b6989f5fb56
      seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod: runtime/default
      creationTimestamp: "2022-01-25T17:02:00Z"
     generateName: airflow-worker-
     labels:
    run: airflow-worker
    managedFields:
   - apiVersion: v1
   fieldsType: FieldsV1
   fieldsV1:
   f:metadata:
     f:annotations:
      .: {}
      f:composer.cloud.google.com/template-version: {}
    f:generateName: {}
    f:labels:
      .: {}
      f:run: {}
    f:ownerReferences:
      .: {}
      k:{"uid":"7ece9e6c-e252-43d9-b989-239d765d375b"}:
        .: {}
        f:apiVersion: {}
        f:blockOwnerDeletion: {}
        f:controller: {}
        f:kind: {}
        f:name: {}
        f:uid: {}
  f:spec:
    f:containers:
      k:{"name":"airflow-worker"}:
        .: {}
        f:args: {}
        f:env:
          .: {}
          k:{"name":"AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:valueFrom:
              .: {}
              f:secretKeyRef:
                .: {}
                f:key: {}
                f:name: {}
          k:{"name":"AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__BASE_URL"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"AIRFLOW_DATABASE_VERSION"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"AIRFLOW_HOME"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"AUTOGKE"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"C_FORCE_ROOT"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"CLOUDSDK_METRICS_ENVIRONMENT"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"COMPOSER_ENVIRONMENT"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"COMPOSER_GKE_LOCATION"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"COMPOSER_GKE_NAME"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"COMPOSER_GKE_ZONE"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
          k:{"name":"COMPOSER_LOCATION"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"COMPOSER_PYTHON_VERSION"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"COMPOSER_VERSION"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"COMPOSER_VERSIONED_NAMESPACE"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"DAGS_FOLDER"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"GCP_PROJECT"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"GCS_BUCKET"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"GCSFUSE_EXTRACTED"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"GRPC_POLL_STRATEGY"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"SQL_DATABASE"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"SQL_HOST"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"SQL_PASSWORD"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:valueFrom:
              .: {}
              f:secretKeyRef:
                .: {}
                f:key: {}
                f:name: {}
          k:{"name":"SQL_SUBNET"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"SQL_USER"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
        f:image: {}
        f:imagePullPolicy: {}
        f:livenessProbe:
          .: {}
          f:exec:
            .: {}
            f:command: {}
          f:failureThreshold: {}
          f:initialDelaySeconds: {}
          f:periodSeconds: {}
          f:successThreshold: {}
          f:timeoutSeconds: {}
        f:name: {}
        f:ports:
          .: {}
          k:{"containerPort":8793,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            .: {}
            f:containerPort: {}
            f:protocol: {}
        f:resources:
          .: {}
          f:limits:
            .: {}
            f:cpu: {}
            f:ephemeral-storage: {}
            f:memory: {}
          f:requests:
            .: {}
            f:cpu: {}
            f:ephemeral-storage: {}
            f:memory: {}
        f:terminationMessagePath: {}
        f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
        f:volumeMounts:
          .: {}
          k:{"mountPath":"/etc/airflow/airflow_cfg"}:
            .: {}
            f:mountPath: {}
            f:name: {}
          k:{"mountPath":"/home/airflow/container-comms"}:
            .: {}
            f:mountPath: {}
            f:name: {}
          k:{"mountPath":"/home/airflow/gcs"}:
            .: {}
            f:mountPath: {}
            f:name: {}
          k:{"mountPath":"/home/airflow/gcsfuse"}:
            .: {}
            f:mountPath: {}
            f:mountPropagation: {}
            f:name: {}
      k:{"name":"gcs-syncd"}:
        .: {}
        f:args: {}
        f:env:
          .: {}
          k:{"name":"AUTOGKE"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"COMPOSER_GKE_LOCATION"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"COMPOSER_GKE_NAME"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"COMPOSER_GKE_ZONE"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
          k:{"name":"GCS_BUCKET"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"SQL_DATABASE"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"SQL_PASSWORD"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:valueFrom:
              .: {}
              f:secretKeyRef:
                .: {}
                f:key: {}
                f:name: {}
          k:{"name":"SQL_SUBNET"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
          k:{"name":"SQL_USER"}:
            .: {}
            f:name: {}
            f:value: {}
        f:image: {}
        f:imagePullPolicy: {}
        f:name: {}
        f:resources:
          .: {}
          f:limits:
            .: {}
            f:cpu: {}
            f:ephemeral-storage: {}
            f:memory: {}
          f:requests:
            .: {}
            f:cpu: {}
            f:ephemeral-storage: {}
            f:memory: {}
        f:terminationMessagePath: {}
        f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
        f:volumeMounts:
          .: {}
          k:{"mountPath":"/home/airflow/gcs"}:
            .: {}
            f:mountPath: {}
            f:name: {}
    f:dnsPolicy: {}
    f:enableServiceLinks: {}
    f:restartPolicy: {}
    f:schedulerName: {}
    f:securityContext: {}
    f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
    f:volumes:
      .: {}
      k:{"name":"airflow-config"}:
        .: {}
        f:configMap:
          .: {}
          f:defaultMode: {}
          f:name: {}
        f:name: {}
      k:{"name":"container-comms"}:
        .: {}
        f:hostPath:
          .: {}
          f:path: {}
          f:type: {}
        f:name: {}
      k:{"name":"gcsdir"}:
        .: {}
        f:emptyDir: {}
        f:name: {}
      k:{"name":"gcsfuse"}:
        .: {}
        f:hostPath:
          .: {}
          f:path: {}
          f:type: {}
        f:name: {}
   manager: manager
   operation: Update
   time: "2022-01-25T17:02:00Z"
   - apiVersion: v1
   fieldsType: FieldsV1
   fieldsV1:
   f:metadata:
    f:annotations:
      f:composer.cloud.google.com/running-task: {}
    manager: OpenAPI-Generator
    operation: Update
    time: "2022-01-25T17:02:33Z"
   - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
   fieldsV1:
     f:status:
    f:message: {}
    f:phase: {}
    f:reason: {}
    f:startTime: {}
    manager: kubelet
   operation: Update
   time: "2022-01-26T10:01:06Z"
   name: airflow-worker-nlzdq
   namespace: composer-2-0-0-airflow-2-1-4-2884adda
   ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: composer.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
   blockOwnerDeletion: true
   controller: true
   kind: AirflowWorkerSet
   name: airflow-worker
   uid: 7ece9e6c-e252-43d9-b989-239d765d375b
   resourceVersion: "27047147"
  uid: b904b45d-0001-4dc4-8f6c-88420d286973
  spec:
     containers:
  - args:
    - worker
    env:
    - name: GRPC_POLL_STRATEGY
    value: epoll1
   - name: CLOUDSDK_METRICS_ENVIRONMENT
    value: 2.1.4+composer
   - name: GCS_BUCKET
   value: us-east4-XYZ-gcp-airflow-p-2884adda-bucket
  - name: GCP_PROJECT
  value: XYZ-259410
- name: COMPOSER_LOCATION
  value: us-east4
- name: COMPOSER_GKE_ZONE
- name: COMPOSER_GKE_NAME
  value: us-east4-XYZ-gcp-airflow-p-2884adda-gke
- name: AUTOGKE
  value: "TRUE"
- name: COMPOSER_GKE_LOCATION
  value: us-east4
- name: COMPOSER_PYTHON_VERSION
  value: "3"
- name: COMPOSER_ENVIRONMENT
  value: XYZ-gcp-airflow-prod-shared-vpc
- name: COMPOSER_VERSIONED_NAMESPACE
  value: composer-2-0-0-airflow-2-1-4-2884adda
- name: AIRFLOW_HOME
  value: /etc/airflow
- name: DAGS_FOLDER
  value: /home/airflow/gcs/dags
 - name: SQL_HOST
  value: airflow-sqlproxy-service.composer- 
 system.svc.cluster.local
- name: SQL_DATABASE
  value: composer-2-0-0-airflow-2-1-4-2884adda
- name: SQL_USER
  value: root
- name: SQL_PASSWORD
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      key: sql_password
      name: airflow-secrets
- name: GCSFUSE_EXTRACTED
  value: "TRUE"
- name: COMPOSER_VERSION
  value: 2.0.0
- name: AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__BASE_URL
  value: https://XYZ-dot-us-east4.composer.googleusercontent.com
- name: SQL_SUBNET
  value: 172.16.2.0/29
- name: AIRFLOW_DATABASE_VERSION
  value: POSTGRES_13
- name: AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN
  value: postgresql+psycopg2://$(SQL_USER):$(SQL_PASSWORD)@airflow-sqlproxy-service.composer-system.svc.cluster.local:3306/$(SQL_DATABASE)
- name: AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      key: fernet_key
      name: airflow-secrets
- name: C_FORCE_ROOT
  value: "TRUE"
image: us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/XYZ-259410/composer-images-us-east4-XYZ-gcp-airflow-p-2884adda-gke/e77f16de-356f-40b5-b42b-f5482f02f793
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - /var/local/worker_checker.py
  failureThreshold: 6
  initialDelaySeconds: 120
  periodSeconds: 90
  successThreshold: 1
  timeoutSeconds: 30
name: airflow-worker
ports:
- containerPort: 8793
  protocol: TCP
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 1700m
    ephemeral-storage: 4Gi
    memory: 6963Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 1700m
    ephemeral-storage: 2Gi
    memory: 6963Mi
securityContext:
  capabilities:
    drop:
    - NET_RAW
terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
terminationMessagePolicy: File
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /etc/airflow/airflow_cfg
  name: airflow-config
- mountPath: /home/airflow/gcs
  name: gcsdir
- mountPath: /home/airflow/container-comms
  name: container-comms
- mountPath: /home/airflow/gcsfuse
  mountPropagation: HostToContainer
  name: gcsfuse
- mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
  name: kube-api-access-59j75
  readOnly: true
 - args:
 - /home/airflow/gcs
 env:
 - name: GCS_BUCKET
   value: us-east4-XYZ-gcp-airflow-p-2884adda-bucket
 - name: SQL_DATABASE
  value: composer-2-0-0-airflow-2-1-4-2884adda
- name: SQL_USER
  value: root
- name: SQL_PASSWORD
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      key: sql_password
      name: airflow-secrets
- name: COMPOSER_GKE_ZONE
- name: COMPOSER_GKE_NAME
  value: us-east4-XYZ-gcp-airflow-p-2884adda-gke
- name: SQL_SUBNET
  value: 172.16.2.0/29
- name: AUTOGKE
  value: "TRUE"
- name: COMPOSER_GKE_LOCATION
  value: us-east4
image: us-docker.pkg.dev/cloud-airflow-releaser/gcs-syncd/gcs-syncd:cloud_composer_service_2021-12-08-RC1
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
name: gcs-syncd
resources:
  limits:
    cpu: 300m
    ephemeral-storage: 102Mi
    memory: 1228Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 300m
    ephemeral-storage: 102Mi
    memory: 1228Mi
securityContext:
  capabilities:
    drop:
    - NET_RAW
terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
terminationMessagePolicy: File
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /home/airflow/gcs
  name: gcsdir
- mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
  name: kube-api-access-59j75
  readOnly: true
 dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
 enableServiceLinks: true
 nodeName: gk3-us-east4-XYZ-gcp-ai-nap-meqa92wv-4be2b93f-5kdv
 preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
 priority: 0
 restartPolicy: Always
 schedulerName: gke.io/optimize-utilization-scheduler
 securityContext:
 seccompProfile:
  type: RuntimeDefault
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
 - effect: NoExecute
 key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
  operator: Exists
  tolerationSeconds: 300
 - effect: NoExecute
   key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
   operator: Exists
   tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - configMap:
   defaultMode: 420
   name: airflow-configmap
   name: airflow-config
  - emptyDir: {}
  name: gcsdir
 - hostPath:
  path: /var/composer/gcs_mount_status
  type: ""
 name: container-comms
- hostPath:
  path: /var/composer/gcs_mount
  type: ""
  name: gcsfuse
 - name: kube-api-access-59j75
  projected:
   defaultMode: 420
  sources:
  - serviceAccountToken:
      expirationSeconds: 3607
      path: token
  - configMap:
      items:
      - key: ca.crt
        path: ca.crt
      name: kube-root-ca.crt
  - downwardAPI:
      items:
      - fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        path: namespace
status:
  message: 'Container airflow-worker exceeded its local ephemeral 
  storage limit "10137Mi". '
  phase: Failed
 reason: Evicted
 startTime: "2022-01-25T17:02:01Z"
```

Comment: Can you share the YAML of the jobs? Why they need these ephemeral volume?

Comment: how can i upload yaml file here

Comment: You don't have to upload the YAMLs. Just paste them in a codeblock. Btw, check the answer provided by @harsh-manvar. This might be the issue.

Comment: @EmruzHossain Added yaml file

Answer (score 2):

Check your **resource quota**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: compute-resources
spec:
  hard:
    requests.ephemeral-storage: 2Gi 
    limits.ephemeral-storage: 4Gi
```

There could be chances if **resource quota** is set and POD `exceeded its local ephemeral storage limit`

Read more about it : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#setting-requests-and-limits-for-local-ephemeral-storage

You can also set the resource in YAML with

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: images.my-company.example/app:v4
    resources:
      requests:
        ephemeral-storage: "2Gi"
      limits:
        ephemeral-storage: "4Gi"
```

Comment: After making the above changes, do i need to restart or what can be done

Comment: I tried updating yaml file with above storage info like 2Gi and 4Gi, but getting this error  "Pod "airflow-worker-nlzdq" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image" not sure what to do next